# How to properly preserve Nginx configuration in Laravel Homestead

Tags: nginx, vagrant, virtualbox, laravel-5.1, homestead

I encounter a problem where when I halt and continue my Homestead VM, the Nginx site configuration is not preserved.

I've made alterations on the configuration and after the halt and continuation the files no longer have these changes I made previously.

Any idea how I can properly preserve the changes on a VM like this?

Comment: do you have provisioning running at startup ? can you try running `vagrant up --no-provision` when you boot the VM after halt

Comment: I'll try that when I need to restart the VM again. Thanks.